# Print equivalent on Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When you execute the following block in Oracle SQL Developer

```
set serveroutput on format wraped;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
end;
```

You get the following response

```
anonymous block completed
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I am basically trying to use PRINT so I can track progress in my PLSQL code.

How do I get rid of the uber-annoying `anonymous block completed`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
set feedback off
```

should suppress the message